# Rendering nested json response data in react UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

This is the structure of the json being fetched. I am trying to render some of the nested threads data to a web page with react.

[image]

```
import react, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactJson from 'react-json-view'

const FeaturedBoards = () => {
    const [boards, setBoards] = useState([{page: '', threads: {}}]); 

useEffect(() => {
    fetchBoards();
}, []);

const fetchBoards = () => {
    axios.get('https://a.4cdn.org/po/catalog.json')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setBoards(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
    if(boards === 0) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    else{
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Featured Boards</h1>
            <div className='item-container'>
                {boards.map((board) => (
                    <div className='board' key={board.id}>
                        <p>{board['threads']}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
};

export default FeaturedBoards;
```

I have tried everything to display some of the nested threads data but nothing comes up. I've tried doing a second call to map on board but no luck, storing it in a variable and calling from that still nothing. Am I doing something totally wrong?

[image]

Comment: Since the `threads` properties in your API data appear to be arrays, why are you initialising it as an object with `useState([{page: '', threads: {}}])`? That's what is causing the error. Also, why initialise with a single-element array in the first place? Why not just `useState([])`?

Comment: my thinking was you had to provide a template structure to be filled in. When I switch useState to that it gives me this error. `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {no, sticky, closed, now, name, sub, com, filename, ext, w, h, tn_w, tn_h, tim, time, md5, fsize, resto, capcode, semantic_url, replies, images, omitted_posts, omitted_images, last_replies, last_modified}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: To this what you said to try  `useState([])` hard to repost the whole code down here lol

Comment: `const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]); `

Comment: Each _board_ `threads` is an array of objects (presumably with properties like `no`, `sticky`, `closed`, etc). `<p>{board['threads']}</p>` just doesn't make sense for that data structure. As the error message says, _"Objects (like the ones in `board.threads`) are not valid as a React child"_

Comment: That was the thing when i use one of those expected keywords like `board['com']` nothing shows up but in the console logs all the data is showing up in the response but then nothing renders on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more fully answered by [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) but to explain for this particular data structure, keep reading.

---

Look at your actual data... `boards` is an array. Each element in it is an object with `page` (int) and `threads` (array) properties. Each `threads` array element is an object with other properties. You can use `map` to iterate arrays and return a JSX representation of the objects within.

For example

```js
const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]); // start with an empty array
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  fetchBoards().then(() => setLoading(false))
}, []);

const fetchBoards = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://a.4cdn.org/po/catalog.json')
  setBoards(data)
}

return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : (
  <div>
    <h1>Featured Boards</h1>
    <div className="item-container">
      {boards.map(board => (
        <div className="board" key={board.page}> <!--  note "page", not "id" -->
          {board.threads.map(thread => (
            <p>{thread.name}</p>
            <p>{thread.sub}</p>
            <p>{thread.com}</p>
            <!-- etc -->
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Worked! thank you that was what I was trying to do, does changing the key={} from id to page do anything?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. Your `board` objects don't appear to have `id` properties so you'd be setting each `key` to `undefined` which would produce _"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."_

Comment: ahhh makes sense from errors I had been seeing, I'll check that out thanks.